# How to iterate through a list and neatly append it to an empty dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which I want to extract some data from and append it to a new data structure.

The data that's used is several years with hourly data for some units.
I have attached some code to highlight the structure as well.

What I'm trying to do is to "automate" the process as much as possible, so that I can change my .csv file to another file with the same structure/headings.

Right now my new dataframe looks kinda bad...

I'm also trying to exclude some years and only have 2018 data, not sure if I'm doing this the proper way.

I tried to concatenate, and it worked fine, but it was quite manual.
I had to split it with manual phrases then concatenate it, seemed like a bad solution. I do however get the output I want when I run it in my graphs now, I just feel the dataframe should be better.

They all have the same index values "hours" while some have blank fields for some part of the day.

```
df_hourly = pd.read_csv('hourlydatafrom2015.txt')

    test_name   unit_name   value   units   Year    Week    Hour
0   35 - Test1  Unit1   814 11  2015    1   11
1   35 - Test1  Unit1   1837    14  2015    1   12
2   35 - Test1  Unit1   5333    41  2015    1   13
3   35 - Test1  Unit1   9726    70  2015    1   14
4   35 - Test1  Unit1   9021    66  2015    1   15

df_hourly = df_hourly[df_hourly.Year > 2018]
df_hourly.loc[df_hourly['Year'] > 2018]

unit_names = df_hourly['unit_name'].unique().tolist()

def single_sorter(name):
    tester_total_units_per_hour = df_hourly[df_hourly['unit_name'] == name].groupby('Hour')[['units']].sum()
    tester_total_units = df_hourly['units'][df_hourly['unit_name'] == name].sum()
    new_tester_units = tester_total_units_per_hour / tester_total_units
    new_tester_units.rename(columns={'units' : '{} units'.format(name)}, inplace=True)
    test_1 = new_tester_units


    return test_1

newer_data_frame = pd.DataFrame ()

for value in unit_names:
    newer_data_frame = newer_data_frame.append(single_sorter(value), ignore_index=False, sort=False)



print(newer_data_frame)

      Unit1 units  nan units  Unit3 units  Unit5 units  Unit2 units  \
Hour                                                                  
9        0.000231        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
10       0.025275        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
11       0.058652        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
12       0.076798        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
13       0.080039        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
14       0.091195        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
15       0.115776        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
16       0.141468        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
17       0.135034        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
18       0.104388        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
19       0.080965        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
20       0.061707        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
21       0.028470        NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
7             NaN        NaN     0.036825          NaN          NaN   
8             NaN        NaN     0.032389          NaN          NaN   
9             NaN        NaN     0.048226          NaN          NaN
```

The list continues, so it seems like it adds index values below instead of using the same index value. I was hoping for a dataframe with index values between 07-21 and then rows for each unit beside it.

I'm an Excel nerd trying to shift to Python, so this might be a really hard/bad way to solve this problem... It looked even worse before I made functions...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The result is normal: append is intended to append new rows to a dataframe. If you want to append columns, you should use `merge` or `join`. As the resulting dataframe should have `Hour` column as index, I would suggest to initialize `newer_data_frame` with all distinct hours from `df_hourly` as index, and consistently join the result of `single_sorter`.

Code would become:

```
...
newer_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(df_hourly.Hour.drop_duplicates()).set_index('Hour')

for value in unit_names:
    newer_data_frame = newer_data_frame.join(single_sorter(value))
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly and just like I wanted it. Had to add .sort_index(), as the values got shuffled a bit.